# Need to understand table structure to scrape webpage

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm having trouble identifying the selector I would need to iterate over some rows and get the cell data from them. It looks like this:

```
<div class="ag-row ag-row-no-focus ag-row-no-animation ag-row-level-0 ag-row-odd" row="1" style="top: 30px; height: 30px;">
    <div class="ag-cell-no-focus ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-value" tabindex="-1" colid="partnerNo" style="width: 60px; left: 0px; user-select: initial; cursor: text;">
    0010734964
    </div>
    <div class="ag-cell-no-focus ag-cell ag-cell-not-inline-editing ag-cell-value" tabindex="-1" colid="partnerName" style="width: 229px; left: 60px;">
    R.A.G. INDUSTRIAL SOLUTIONS, I NC
    </div>
</div>
```

The rows alternate as `ag-row-even` and `ag-row-odd` and so on. All of the tutorials I've read describe a `td` and `tr` structure, but I'm not seeing any elements like that here.

I would like to be able to loop through each row by that row number, but I don't understand how to get that element. The selector for each row seems to be unique. Further, I'd like to get the cells as properties of class objects generated from those rows. I was able to do something similar with a different weird table like so:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    var myIndex = (120 + (i + 1));
    soldToSelector = '#statictext9Mq9nPD4a42Lyx9hdaUFY0_14-listdefintiona5uG8xn1wqkvGe3jrjPaCW_11-cloneINDEX';
    soldToValue = soldToSelector.replace("INDEX", i);
    soldToElement =  await page.$(soldToValue);
    myText =   await page.evaluate(soldToElement => soldToElement.textContent, soldToElement);
    accountsArray.push(new Account((myIndex), myText));
}
```

But in that case, the only difference between selectors was the number at the end, so that was easy enough to loop through and change. Any ideas?

Comment: That's [ag-grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/example.php#/).  Puppeteer can select by class so `ag-row` is the row, loop over those and then loop over `ag-cell` which are the cells.

Comment: would I just use ag-row as the selector? Same structure?

Comment: When I try to access that element using `ag-row` as a selector I get undefined. Please advise.

Comment: Are you using `querySelectorAll(".ag-row")`?

Comment: For that it returns "page.querySelectorAll is not a function" and when I try document, it says that document is undefined. I'm very confused and I would appreciate an explanation wherein I'm treated like a fool, which I am.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.ag-row` to target the rows and `.ag-cell` to target each cell.  You can then also use `.ag-row > .ag-cell:nth-child(n)` to target columns where `n` is the column number.

Here is a an example:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto('https://www.ag-grid.com/example.php#/');

const names = await page.evaluate(() => {
  const firstColumnCells = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.ag-row > .ag-cell:nth-child(1)'));
  return firstColumnCells.map(cell => cell.innerText);
});

console.log(names);

await browser.close();
```

You can test this example on real data from the [demo of Ag-Grid](https://www.ag-grid.com/example.php#/) with the [Try Puppeteer app](https://try-puppeteer.appspot.com/) by copying the above code into the app and clicking "Run It".

Comment: Steven, you're a gentleman and a scholar. Thank you for your continued help with this matter.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the row is identified by the "row" attribute. You could try something like this to get the row data:

```
let rows = document.querySelectorAll('[row]');

rows.forEach( (s, i) =>  {

  var cells = s.childNodes;
  cells.forEach( (node , j) => {
    if( node.innerText ) {
      console.log( 'text', j, node.innerText );
      // do something with the text values
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: Thank you! This seems like it should work. I had to modify it a bit because I was getting that document undefined error, so I did this:

let rows = await page.evaluate(
  () => document.querySelectorAll('[row]')
    );

rows.forEach( (s, i) =>  {

  var cells = s.childNodes;
  cells.forEach( (node , j) => {
    if( node.innerText ) {
      console.log( 'text', j, node.innerText );
      // do something with the text values
    }

Now it says it cannot read the forEach property of undefined (row, in this case) any ideas?